# Cannot run Composer update and install command

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to do the composer install and update on my Laravel project and it is not working. It is giving me an output. Could anyone tell me what should be done?

```
export PATH=/opt/sp/php7.1/bin:$PATH
php /opt/sp/bin/composer.phar "$@"
```

I am using Ubuntu18.04

Comment: do you have composer installed?

Comment: What do you mean by "giving me an output"?